# How can I send wysiwyg editor code to php by ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have nicEditor wysiwyg editor in my page (textarea tag) .

I want to send the output of the code editor to php page by ajax , this is my request .

Comment: get `<textarea>` value, `escape()` it, and send it? Could you explain what's your problem?

Comment: I have nicEditor wysiwyg editor in my page and I want to send the output of the HTML code editor to php page by ajax , this is my request

Comment: Everything is in `<div>` element. You have to find it, get `innerHTML`, `escape()` it and send it to your PHP script. Anyway, we don't know where is your problem..

Comment: @atlavis - I found it, but it does not have id attr

Comment: This is not just to you, @Lion King, but please don't repeat what you've said in your OP. People ask questions because the OP doesn't have enough information. Posting the same again does not make 2x more information - 2x0=0.

Comment: Do this first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24451065/888177  Then you can get the value of the textarea and insert it into the data of a jquery ajax, post or get.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a php `require` to include any type of file:

textarea.html:

```
<textarea>
//htmlcode
</textare>
```

page.php:

```
 <?php
 //php code
 require "textarea.html"
 ?>
```

is that what you are talking about?
Or are you refering to using javascript to get html code from the file?

Comment: I may be wrong here, but I think you are using the term Ajax wrong. If you are just using php & html code, that is not Ajax (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know exactly how nicEdit works, but according to nicedit.com, it just changes all `<textarea>`s to rich html editors. I'm guessing you can still refer to the textareas the same way, which would by to do what @atlavis said:

```
<textarea id='text1'></textarea>

<script>
var textarea document.getElementById('text1').value;
textarea = escape(textarea);

//now send textarea to the php with a XHR request

</script
```

Comment: Unfortunately did not happen anything